# convert an object back to its oiginal class?

Tags: java, class, object, casting

Before I start I have read other related questions but can not seem to understand the answers given as i have tried the answers and they do not appear to work for me.
I have a Dog class that has been placed into the object list. I have then created a new object g and assigned it to the value of the object class containing the dog.  However this does not give me the original properties of the dog. How can I revert g back to class Dog?

```
ObjectList ol = new ObjectList(3);
Dog d = new Dog(4,"pug","Doug");
ol.add(d);

//some code later...

Object g = ol.getObject(1);
g.bark();
```

This doesn't work due to d losing its properties of dog.  Any help?  Thanks.

Comment: Be wary of thinking you need to do this; it's often a sign of impending doom.

Comment: Unrelated comment: please make sure you add relevant tags on your questions. The [tag:dog] tag is actually for a programming langage, not `Dog` variables/types in your code.

Comment: Also, be aware that you have *not* created "a new object". You've created a new *reference*, that points to the same Dog object. You just can't access the Dog API through the Object reference.

Comment: sorry still learning how to use this, ok thanks for the information. Its not that i want to do this its that my lecturer wants me to do this !! anyway sorry probably should of phrased the question better. The code above is a sample of the question given i must modify this as well as other parts to work however i have hit this part and am just stuck i have read other questions similar but do not entirely understand the answers given. @AndyThomas

Comment: @Josh - You can cast the reference of type Object to a reference of type Dog, if you know that the object to which the reference points is actually a Dog object. The same question asked before, cited above, shows how to do that. You can do `Dog d1 = (Dog) g;`. Usually, you only want to do that cast after testing that it's actually a dog with `if ( g instanceof Dog ) { ... }`.

Comment: @AndyThomas Oh, well that's embarrassing ive been trying to use "instanceof"  but spelling it with a capital "O".  i originally tried this but it still   says method ".bark" cant be found for g, which is so confusing ill try figure something out.. anyway thanks for the help man much appreciated.

Comment: Casting just changes the type of a value. It does not change the type of the variable `g`. If you cast `g` and store the results in `d1`, then you can use `d1.bark()`. You can also cast `g` without storing it, like this: `((Dog) g).bark()`. Note the first set of parantheses are required. If you instead said `(Dog) g.bark()`, that would be interpreted as attempting to cast the return value of `g.bark()`.

Comment: @AndyThomas That makes so much sense, and it works. Thank you so much !!!! greatly appreciated. I think you should replace our lecturer haha cheers man.

Comment: If people suggest other questions/answers to look at (including links to possible duplicates) and they don't work for you, tell us what that means. Describe specific errors or bad results you got when trying to implement those other solutions, and share the code for your attempted implementations.